# jQuery How to auto sync groups of radio buttons

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have the following web form markup:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="option[1]" class="abc">
<input type="radio" value="2" name="option[1]" class="def">
<input type="radio" value="3" name="option[1]" class="ghi">
<input type="radio" value="1" name="option[2]" class="abc">
<input type="radio" value="2" name="option[2]" class="def">
<input type="radio" value="3" name="option[2]" class="ghi">
<input type="radio" value="1" name="option[3]" class="abc">
<input type="radio" value="2" name="option[3]" class="def">
<input type="radio" value="3" name="option[3]" class="ghi">
```

How can I set the `option[2]` and `option[3]` buttons to get the same selection made for `option[1]`?

Can it be done with some sort of jQuery assignment or do I need to create my own set of if/then statements?

**Here is my if/then statements (it works, just looking to make it a bit more concise):**

```
if ( $('input.abc[name="option\\[1\\]"]').prop('checked') == true) {
  $('input.abc[name="option\\[2\\]"]').prop('checked', true);
  $('input.abc[name="option\\[3\\]"]').prop('checked', true);
}
else if ( $('input.def[name="option\\[1\\]"]').prop('checked') == true) {
  $('input.def[name="option\\[2\\]"]').prop('checked', true);
  $('input.def[name="option\\[3\\]"]').prop('checked', true);
}
else if ( $('input.ghi[name="option\\[1\\]"]').prop('checked') == true) {
  $('input.ghi[name="option\\[2\\]"]').prop('checked', true);
  $('input.ghi[name="option\\[3\\]"]').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post the jQuery you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Ok, thanks @j08691...I was hoping to get some direction before heading off with if/then statements. But I'll go ahead and do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle. I have added a solution.

1. Select the first set of inputs with option1, bind event on it.
2. Get selected input element's value.
3. Select the inputs with the common value and assign them as checked.

http://jsfiddle.net/n8CdM/751/

```
    $('input[name="option1"]').on('click', function () {
       var selection = $(this).val();
       $('input[value="' + selection + '"]').attr('checked', true);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name="option[1]"]').change(function () {
    $('input[name="option[2]"],input[name="option[3]"]').val([$(this).val()])
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/n8DR8/)**

Comment: very cool tool @j08691 -- beats my lengthy heavy-handed lines of code.

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="option[1]" class="class1">
<input type="radio" value="2" name="option[1]" class="class2">
<input type="radio" value="3" name="option[1]" class="class3">
<input type="radio" value="1" name="option[2]" class="class1">
<input type="radio" value="2" name="option[2]" class="class2">
<input type="radio" value="3" name="option[2]" class="class3">
<input type="radio" value="1" name="option[3]" class="class1">
<input type="radio" value="2" name="option[3]" class="class2">
<input type="radio" value="3" name="option[3]" class="class3">
```

add classes to inputs and try jquery code:

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
   $("."+$(this).attr('class')).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

for example ;)

Comment: i gave the same solution like author used but without if/else statement ;_;

Answer (score -2):

you could add an attribute to the html

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="option[2]" checked="checked" >
```

Or you could add it with jQuery

```
$('input[name="option[2]"]').attr('checked','checked');
```